# Как создать дочерний класс внутри класса родителя, и вызвать методы дочернего класса внутри класса родителя

Tags: c#, winforms, ооп

Создаю класс наследник:

```
public partial class changeUser : Form
{
    public class changeUserChild 
    {
       //some methods
       void read_from_file()
       {
          //some code
       }

    }

    public changeUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create object of a class change user 
        changeUserChild CChangeUser=new changeUserChild();
        CChangeUser.read_from_file();

    }
}
```

Вот на этом моменте

> changeUserChild CChangeUser=new changeUserChild();

возникает ошибка.

Прога виснет. 
Отладчик выдает следующее необработанное исключение:

> System.OutOfMemoryException

Полагаю что при объявлении дочернего класса таким образом, у меня возникает рекурсия вызова конструктора инициализации родительского класса. Так как затрачиваемая память процессора с момента начала выполнения создания объекта на дочерний класс начинает сильно расти.

Подскажите, каким образом можно исправить данную проблему?

Comment: покажите конструктор `changeUserChild`

Comment: @Igor, я не создавал конструктор `changeUserChild`

Comment: дак у вас там файл небось размером больше чем объем оперативки. ну или что вы там делаете в с этим файлом. С большой рекурсией у вас скорее выпало бы со `stackoverflow` (это если допустить что у вас функция рекурсивная, а так там не может быт рекурсии самой по себе никак)

Comment: @teran, не совсем так, файл весит всего 1 кб, но потребляемая память процессора при создании объекта растет с 2 до 500 мб при зависании.. Да, и программа не доходит до момента `  CChangeUser.read_from_file();`. При удалении этой строки, проблема не проходит.

Comment: значит код `read_from_file` чудит где то. добавьте его в вопрос

Comment: в строке `changeUserChild CChangeUser=new changeUserChild();` нет ничего, что объясняло бы поведение, которое Вы описываете

Comment: @Bulson отдельную внутреннюю логику довольно часто выносят в приватный вложенный класс и дергают хоть всеми ногами одновременно потом.

Comment: @Bulson, дело в том, что в классе родителе, есть элементы управления (textBox'ы), информацию с которых мне нужно читать. Если  описывать все методы в том же классе, где создаются данные объекты управления, получается громоздкий код, хотелось бы сделать код более удобным для работы, для чего я и решил создать дополнительный класс. Если не наследовать данный класс, то нужно изменять все элементы управления в базовом классе при объявлении на static, а вместе с этим много чего, а лезть в дебри не хотелось бы.

Comment: @Bulson "Паттерн" не догма, а руководство к действию. Карл Маркс

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо за поздравления. Но только мне все таки хотелось бы разобраться в проблеме, даже если мое решение создать вложенный класс было ошибочным.

Comment: @engineer_7 - Оставьте у себя в проекте только тот код, который Вы привели в вопросе. Ошибка не происходит. Нам кода из вопроса тоже недостаточно.

Comment: @Bulson очевидно приватный вложенный класс делают, когда хотят вынести некую приватную логику в отдельную сущность. С таким же целями в некоторых языках существуют вложенные функции и т.п. Почему вы думаете, что если класс вложенный, то должен быть вообще доступен снаружи? может он внутренние задачи решает.

Comment: @teran, собственно он и решает внутренние задачи

Comment: @Igor, закомментил весь код внутри данного класса, ситуация не изменилась

Comment: @engineer_7 Я могу только еще раз повторить, что код из вопроса не соответствует описываемому поведению. Код из вопроса вообще не компилируется.